# how to get hidden value with pagination in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, get, pagination

when in the first page, the hiddenvalue can be gotten. so, there is no problem but after the page index is changed , the hiddenfieldvalue cannot be gotten by user. İt shows error which is about "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException" when trying to get  hiddenvalue

```
(string sValue = ((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
```

asp side:

```
        <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="sayfa_adeti" HeaderText="SAYFA ADETİ"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="60px"></asp:BoundField>
              </asp:BoundField>

   <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server"Value='<%#Eval("ID")%>'</asp:HiddenField>   

  protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    getOncekiFotokopiTalepler();//fillGrid
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

c#side

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    //int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
    int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument.ToString().Trim());


    if (e.CommandName == "Goruntule")
    {
        string sValue = ((HiddenField)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("HiddenField1")).Value;
        GridViewRow gvRow = GridView1.Rows[rowIndex];

        Session["SELECTED_FOTOKOPI_TALEP_ID"] = sValue;
        Response.Redirect("~/fotokopiTalebimiGor.aspx");
    }

}
```

Comment: so, if you pick the 3rd row on page 2, what is the rowIndex value?  My guess is that you're getting the datasource row index and trying to apply it to the gridview row index which is only 1 page of data (ie 10 items) and you're indexing item 13 - for example.

Comment: What is the value of "rowIndex" when the code fails?
Some more code would have been useful, since we cannot see how you trigger RowCommand. If it's by a linkbutton, for example, you could use the CommandArgument property of the LinkButton and set THAT to "ID" instead of using a HiddenField.

Comment: for example in 3rd page, my rowIndex value is 13, also when i click to linkbutton, rowcommand function works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this:

```
int rowIndex = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument) % GridView1.PageSize;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with CommandSource.

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    var control = e.CommandSource as Control;
    var gridViewRow = control.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    int rowIndex = gridViewRow.RowIndex;

    ....
}
```